# Is it safe to store asset files under sub root folder?

Tags: php, web

My app will store an uploaded image file under `https:\\domain.com\asset\userid\` directory according to this code:

```
$folder = $object->upload_dir.$user_id.DS;
if (!file_exists($folder)) {
    mkdir($folder, 0770, true);
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $folder.$filename);
chmod($folder.$filename, 0660);
```

Is it safe to do that considering hacker can write a script, let's under `https:\\domain.com\asset\` directory and delete all the image files altogether?

Comment: If a hacker can upload a script to your server then there is very little you can do.  How can the server know the difference between a script you've uploaded and a script someone else has.

Comment: Well, store images outside of `public_html`.

Comment: How can a hacker upload a script file? You need to check for image extensions.

Comment: @vivek If I put outside public_html, then how can the app access the files?

Comment: @vivek allowed image extension is only jpg.

Comment: @user1801605 Well, you need to fetch it base64 encoded I presume when someone requests the file.

Comment: @user1801605 But your code doesn't have any validation for that.

Comment: @vivek The validation is handled by the client (app).

Comment: @user1801605 You can also have some server settings to make the user visible only an image instead of a complete listing when someone  requests `yoursite.com/assets/images/45` via .htaccess if your server is using Apache. Nginx server should have something similar.

Comment: @user1801605 Server side validation is always necessary regardless. It's not difficult to reverse engineer the app to get the API URL and try it with Postman tool.

Comment: @vivek. The index is already off so I think hacker won't be able to see the list of the files. Besides there is an empty index.php on every folder.

Comment: @user1801605 Not sure if you are using a framework but a simple `Options -Indexes` in .htaccess should do the same.

Comment: I meant, only the jpg validation is done within the client side. All other stuff (like credentials) is done in the server side.

Comment: My only concern is if it is possible for a hacker to put an evil script onto the root folder. I'm not a PHP guru, so I really have no idea if this possible or not.

Comment: I use nginx and have put this command `autoindex off;` in the conf file.

Comment: @user1801605 JPG validation should be done on server side as well. And if you properly sanitize inputs, there is hardly any way for the hacker to upload an evil script.